# How can I capture an image from a preview video stream from the device camera using custom renderer view xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm implementing biometric facial authentication in my Xamarin.forms app (Android and iOS). I am basing myself on this example to capture the user's face which implements custom renderer (Android), but in this example: https://github.com/UNIT-23/Xam-Android-Camera2-Sample the image must be touched to capture it, I would like to capture this image every 3 seconds without the user having to touch, like second option I would like to capture the photo with a button, but I don't really know how to implement it, so any help or example suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help and your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Threading.Timer?view=net-6.0)

Alternatively, for Xamarin.Forms, you have access to a cross-platform Timer via the Device class:

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
{
    // called every 1 second
    // do stuff here

    return true; // return true to repeat counting, false to stop timer
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. in my case i was looking for a more complex solution by trying to call the method from the view, but sending the image from the renderer to the view works! Thank you, have a nice day.

Comment: your wlc @Luis.